# Extracting Records which 'No' Criteria only

Tags: sql

I have a view in SQL which retrieves the below result:

```
Emp ID  First Name  Last Name   Made payment bigger than $2000 in last 12 months
10023   Keith   Brown           NO
10023   Keith   Brown           NO
10023   Keith   Brown           YES
31522   Maxine  Wood            NO
31522   Maxine  Wood            NO
31522   Maxine  Wood            YES
31522   Maxine  Wood            YES
31522   Maxine  Wood            NO
32007   Mark    Taylor          NO
32007   Mark    Taylor          NO
32007   Mark    Taylor          NO
32007   Mark    Taylor          NO
32012   Christopher Benson      YES
32034   William Cecchini        NO
32034   William Cecchini        NO
32034   William Cecchini        NO
32034   William Cecchini        NO
32037   Gregory Thomas          NO
32037   Gregory Thomas          NO
32037   Gregory Thomas          NO
32037   Gregory Thomas          NO
32037   Gregory Thomas          NO
32037   Gregory Thomas          NO
32037   Gregory Thomas          YES
```

I want a result with employees who results with "NO" but not "YES"..... or if rephrased, employees who are "NO" only

My limitations are I cannot use a declared variable to extract this info.

The Result Set I am looking from above View is

```
Emp ID  First Name  Last Name
32007   Mark    Taylor
32034   William Cecchini
```

Any help or direct would be highly appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT EmpID, First, Last FROM Table WHERE EmpID NOT IN 
(
    SELECT EmpID FROM Table WHERE MadePayment='Yes'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative with conditional aggregation:

```
select id, firstname, lastname
from yourtable
group by id, firstname, lastname
having sum(case when madepayment != 'no' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4e033/1)